# Regex: Find files not ending with numeral suffix

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I need to make a command which returns all files without numeral suffix (*.0, *.123, ...)

Have for example three files:

```
gg.p  qqq.449  rtr55
```

I want to find only these:

```
./rtr55
./gg.p
```

I tried to find them using grep. However I got only results with no effect.

```
find -type f | grep -v '\.[0-9]+$'
```

(This command returned:)

```
./qqq.449
./rtr55
./gg.p
```

So there is probably some regex format error. Do you know, how to fix it?

Comment: Try `grep -v '\.[0-9]\+$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator belongs to the extended regular expressions. There are many workarounds:

```
find -type f | grep -v '\.[0-9]\+$'
find -type f | egrep -v '\.[0-9]+$'
find -type f | grep -E -v '\.[0-9]+$'
find -type f | grep -v '\.[0-9][0-9]*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `grep` at all?

```
find -regex '.*\.[0-9][0-9]*' -prune -o -type f
```

If your expressions are simple enough (or your `find` doesn't support `-regex`), you could use `-name` instead of `-regex` but a glob wildcard can't capture an arbitrary amount of numbers after the dot.  Here's one or two:

```
find -name '*.[0-9]' -prune -o -name '*.[0-9][0-9]' -prune -o -type f
```

Notice that this isn't purely an efficiency question; `grep` would simply not do the right thing if you ever come across file names with newlines in them.

Comment: The regex support in `find` on MacOS doesn't support `[0-9]+` so I put in a slightly more cumbersome expression.  I guess on Linux you probably can use the plus quantifier but notice that it's not portable.

Comment: I tried find -regex '.*\.[0-9][0-9]*' -prune -o -type f, but it has no effect on numerals return. Moreover -regex option isnt probably in accordance with standard. When I pasted it to SunOS, it didnt recognize the -regex option.

Comment: Updated with a version which uses -name only.